# Get checkbox value without page refresh

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, get

I got a table of checkboxes:

```
<td><input id="box" name="box" type="checkbox" value="1" checked /></td>
<td><input id="box" name="box" type="checkbox" value="2" checked /></td>
<td><input id="box" name="box" type="checkbox" value="3" checked /></td>
```

I want to submit checkbox value when I check or uncheck the box (each one at a time) **Without refreshing** the page to:

```
if (isset($_GET['box'])) {
   echo "Success!"
}
```

By far I got this javascript code to check whether the box is checked or unchecked:

```
function validate(){ 
if (document.getElementById('box').checked){
    alert("checked") ;
}else{
    alert("You didn't check it! Let me check it for you.")
}
}
```

I want to add AJAX on it, but all the snippet code I try so far didn't fit good with my code. I'll thank for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not simple. Learn about Ajax, and then use complex library methods to write it *short*.

Comment: Do you have some javascript so far ?

Comment: @Danny AJAX, but not with great success...

Comment: Make a jQuery Ajax call to a PHP script when you check each box and you'll get it that way. You can't do it with PHP alone sadly. Can you post your code?

Comment: I'll thank if someone can post a code snippet, I'm stuck in the middle of the project.

Comment: So I posted how to do this from the client side with jQuery. You probably want to read some other posts here on how to handle the backend in PHP (and whatever framework you're using if you are using a framework).

Answer (score 5):

You want to use AJAX. Here is an example in jQuery without AJAX:

```
<td><input id="box1" class="box" name="box1" type="checkbox" value="1" checked /></td>
<td><input id="box2" class="box" name="box2" type="checkbox" value="2" checked /></td>
<td><input id="box3" class="box" name="box3" type="checkbox" value="3" checked /></td>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box').on('change', function(event) {
    var checkbox = $(event.target);
    var isChecked = $(checkbox).is(':checked');
    alert('checkbox ' + checkbox.attr('id') + ' is checked: ' + isChecked);
  });
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ipasud/1/

Now instead of doing an `alert` call, do a $.post to a backend URL that takes an id and a value of checked or unchecked. For example,

```
$.post('/submit-checkbox.php', {id: checkbox.attr('id'), value: isChecked});
```

And if we put that back into the code, it would look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box').on('change', function(event) {
    var checkbox = $(event.target);
    var isChecked = $(checkbox).is(':checked');
    $.post('/whatever-your-url-is.php', {id: checkbox.attr('id'), value: isChecked});
  });
});
```

Comment: Ok, I get an alert when I check/uncheck. But, when I insert the $.post statement I get a blank screen? Where do i suppose to put it in my code? And where php "get" statement come into place?

Comment: Well what is on the PHP side? Are you listening for a POST or a GET to submit to when the checkbox is changed? I updated it with an example but you need to `$.post` or `$.get` to whatever URL (endpoint) you are going to listen to on the server for this data. Using the POST instead of GET to submit the data is more correct (you'll have less issues doing it that way).

Comment: <?php  

echo '<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>';
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/get.js"></script>';

if (isset($_POST['box1'])) {
 echo $_POST['box1'];
}

if (isset($_POST['box2'])) {
 echo $_POST['box2'];
}

echo '<td><input id="box1" class="box" name="box1" type="checkbox" value="1" checked /></td>';
echo '<td><input id="box2" class="box" name="box2" type="checkbox" value="1" checked /></td>';

?>

Comment: I get nothing... (get.js = your function above).

Comment: So you need to go look at how AJAX works with PHP and jQuery. It is kind of complicated. Here is one example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example But you can google for more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery: http://jquery.com/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#box').click(function(){
           var selectedValue = $(this).value();
           submitValue(selectedValue);
        });

    });

    function submitValue(valueSelected){

       var request = $.ajax({
                 url: URL_OF_YOUR_PHP_FILE,
                 type: "POST",
                 dataType: 'json',
                     data: {value: valueSelected}
              });

        request.done(function(results) {
           //DO WHAT YOU WANT WITH YOUR RESULTS
        });
    }
</script>
```

Then in your PHP file you can get the value selected in $_POST['value'] and return what you want (in JSON format).